# (.*) redirect loop Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, redirect-loop

Trying to proper make a redirect loop for site

tryng to redirect all sites like

34www.arsenal.org.pl / 46www.arsenal.org.pl /   ww32w.arsenal.org.pl  /     dalx.arsenal.org.pl

to arsenal.org.pl

http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php gave me the code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://arsenal.org.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it give redirect loop in Wordpress

Comment: Of course it loops, because when the client is requesting anything from the domain `arsenal.org.pl` already, you redirect to that very same address … again. You need to precede your RewriteRule with a RewriteCond that checks the host name of the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)arsenal.org.pl$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.arsenal.org.pl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://arsenal.org.pl/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

ty Cbroe for hint :)